# Перерисовка в Device Context

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, gdi, gdi+

Привет всем. Я тут новенький. По диплому занимаюсь с GDI+/GDI.

Вопрос такой: Как в GDI(или GDI+) в автоматическом режиме перерисовать изображение или фигуры в DC?
Поподробней: Я пытаюсь сделать аналог Экранной лупы из мобильного телефона. Тач скрин телефона будет являться этой самой лупой для ПК. Сейчас я добился того, чтобы мое изображение, которое будет являться окружностью с прозрачным центром, отрисовывалось на экране (DC). Но, как только я беру в фокус другое окно (или просто меняю его), то оно, что логично, зарисовывает мое изображение. Как мне этого избежать?

Чтобы было понятней, вот мой код. Он тестовый, поэтому не обращайте внимания, что его мало для диплома:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
int main()
{
    HDC hdc = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), 0, 0, 0);

    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Graphics graph(hdc);
    Image* image = new Image(L"C:\\bitmapCursor.jpg");

    printf("The width of the image is %u.\n", image->GetWidth());
    printf("The height of the image is %u.\n", image->GetHeight());
    graph.DrawImage(image, 100, 100, 640, 640);

    //delete image;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не-не, так не пойдёт.

В WinAPI для отображения нужен message loop. В него приходит [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint), в котором и должна происходить отрисовка.

Простой метод перерисовать объект — вызвать функцию [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect), которое сообщит, что часть вашего UI должна быть перерисована. Графическая подсистема проверит, видим ли этот участок на экране, объединит его с другими инвалидированными прямоугольниками, и пошлёт вашему окну через некоторое время `WM_PAINT`.

([Здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/using-the-wm-paint-message) официальная документация.)

Если вы хотите перерисовать что-то *немедленно*, вы можете нарисовать прямо в device context (который вы должны получить при помощи функции [`GetDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc)), но это не отменяет необходимости правильной обработки `WM_PAINT`.

---

Вот [здесь](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030723-00/?p=43073) костяк правильной программы, которая рисует интерфейс на чистом WinAPI.

Comment: Спасибо. Я так думал делать. Еще думаю, точнее. А что с этим делом в GDI+? Если вам не трудно

Comment: @АлексейЦуров: По существу, большой разницы нет. В GDI+ вы просто вместо device context'а пользуетесь классом [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), который предоставляет [немного больше возможностей](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Всё остальное, включая message loop, остаётся почти таким же, с [незначительными по сути изменениями](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Понятно. По изучал я немного то, что вы мне показали и сделал вывод, что еще одну, фактически, мышку мне создать не удастся. Только если изменения с существующей. Те не менее вопрос: Реально ли создать обьект без оконной рамки и по функциональности равной мыши?

Comment: @АлексейЦуров: Ого, вы замахнулись на серьёзную вещь. Думаю, здесь вам GDI не поможет, так как мышь обслуживается на гораздо более низком уровне. Например, она не является окном, и не принимает оконные сообщения. Создать объект без оконной рамки можно, это как раз не проблема.

Comment: Как? Я просмотрел кучу примеров и туториалов (до книжек пока тока не добрался) и нигде не нашел ничего подходящего. Дохожу до части перерисовки и все.

Comment: @АлексейЦуров: Посмотрите флаги [`CreateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `dwStyle` позволяет отключать рамки, title bar, кнопки и всякое такое. Вот [список значений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (можно побитово объединять). Если этого мало, есть ещё [`CreateWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @АлексейЦуров: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7443329/276994